# Load a page server-side and deliver to web browser

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a raspberry pi project where i've set up a media centre with an apache web-interface over my LAN. I've recently installed the deluge-web browser GUI for managing torrents which runs over a different port.

I'm forwarding port 80 so that I can access the media center interface when i'm away from home for management, but would like to get it set up so i can access the deluge-web ui without having to forward its port, so that i can implement a stricter security control using mysql or php with apache.

So what i'm trying to do is set up a frame which is loading the deluge-web ui on the server-side, visible and accessible by the browser.

I'm running apache 2.2.22, php 5.4.39, raspian (debian 7.8).

Is that it all possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. A frame is a client side technology. It can't do anything about permissions or creating network paths to internal servers.

If you want to make a service accessible with added authentication, then you'll need to look at using something like an SSH tunnel or HTTP proxy instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, what youre looking for is curl. Check [Curl Documentation on PHP Site](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Basically, it can download any url (page/file/whatever) and then you can use it in your php script, possibly dumping it into an iframe or div.